# IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 22?

Tags: python, keras, encoding, nlp, decoding

while working on english to hindi i got an error "IndexError: index 22 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 22" .LSTM network

```
def generate_batch(X = X_train, y = y_train, batch_size = 128):
    ''' Generate a batch of data '''
    while True:
        for j in range(1, len(X), batch_size):
            encoder_input_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_src),dtype='float32')
            decoder_input_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_tar),dtype='float32')
            decoder_target_data = np.zeros((batch_size, max_length_tar, num_decoder_tokens),dtype='float32')
            for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(X[j:j+batch_size], y[j:j+batch_size])):
                for t, word in enumerate(input_text.split()):
                    encoder_input_data[i, t] = input_token_index[word] # encoder input seq
                for t, word in enumerate(target_text.split()):
                    if t<len(target_text.split())-1:
                        decoder_input_data[i, t] = target_token_index[word] # decoder input seq #erro point
                    if t>0:
                        # decoder target sequence (one hot encoded)
                        # does not include the START_ token
                        # Offset by one timestep
                        decoder_target_data[i, t - 1, target_token_index[word]] = 1.
            yield([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data)
```

Comment: The last addressable index is 21.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but this looks like a classic off-by-one error.

If the list is of size 22, the last index-able position is 21. This is because the indices for lists start at 0.

From the code given it is hard to tell exactly where in the code this problem originates from.